# First basic android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I had started learning android development and have done most of the ui basics. Now I want to create my own app to know how much I have actually learned. I think all android devs started with one app so which one is the most basic app to create.
Only UI elements,
And no service, broadcast receivers and sq lite stuff. Have not got there yet

Comment: Create an app to show both the twitter and facebook feeds, or an app that will fly to mars

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, for example, google out something like "My first android app"

Something like this is likely to come up:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dE1b_qOx4_g